# How to download skype video message from the cloud?

Tags: video, download, skype

I need to forward a video message from a contact to another contact. Skype (v. 7.14.85.106) gives me this link which opens in a browser window. After examining the streams through Chrome's network analyzer, I found the video stream which goes like this:

https://api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/_some_guid/views/video/ it opens up and plays the stream in some kind of player.

Question: How do I download this video and convert it to a playable format like MP4?

Answer (score 0):

I found the right link in the other tab in google's network inspector, something like this: https://luX.media.vm.skype.com/vod/flvs-play?assetId=X&profile=flvs-normal, download it with wget, and video is stored as flv, which is a common format. With ffmpeg you can convert it into any other format.